# Anúncio SO.pt Beta

Tags: bug, status-aceito, design

Os anúncios do Stack Overflow em Português no Stack Overflow ainda estão apresentando a versão Beta:

<kbd>[image: StackOverflow em Português]</kbd>

Comment: Verdade... Isso me lembra que a nossa segunda leva de anúncios no SOen nunca saiu do chão....

Comment: Há um comentário de ontem sobre o assunto: [pt-SO ads are outdated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317328/pt-so-ads-are-outdated)... :)